# docker postgres with initial data is not persisted over commits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I created a rails app in a docker environment and it links to a postgres instance. I edited the
postgres container to add initial data (by running rake db:setup from the rails app). Now I commited the postgres database, but it doesn't seem to remember my data when I create a new container (of the commited postgres image).

Isn't it possible to save data in a commit and then reuse it afterwards?

I used the postgres image: https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: There is a way to add initial data to a postgres docker image: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54993271/274811 This comes with downsides, also discussed there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that the postgres Dockerfile declares "/var/lib/postgresql/data" as a volume. This is a just a normal directory that lives outside of the Union File System used by images. Volumes live until no containers link to them and they are explicitly deleted.

You have a few choices:

- Use the `--volumes-from` command to share data with new containers. This will only work if there is only one running postgres image at a time, but it is the best solution.
- Write your own Dockerfile which creates the data before declaring the volume. This data will then be copied into the volume when the container is created.
- Write an entrypoint or cmd script which populates the database at run time.

All of these suggestions require you to use Volumes to manage the data once the container is running. Alternatively, you could write your own Dockerfile and simply not declare a volume. You could then use `docker commit` to create a new image after adding data. This will probably work in the short term, but is definitely not how you should work with containers - it isn't repeatable and you will eventually run out of layers in the Union File System.

Have a look at the official Docker docs on [managing data in containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) for more info.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to run some tests in parallel in a CI environment and wanted to give each set of tests their own database with pre-loaded data to run against.  Is my only option to not use the standard postgres image?

Comment: Well, the choices are the same. In this case, I would probably create your own image by modifying the Dockerfile for the official Postgres image.

Comment: Nowadays you can also set the `PGDATA` enviroment variable to change the data directory to another, outside the volume.

Comment: As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753596/4494577) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956964/4494577) answer.

Answer (score 18):

Create a new Dockerfile and change `PGDATA`:

```
FROM postgres:9.2.10

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql-static/data
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql-static/data
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works, but it is amazing. Thank you

Comment: I don't see it on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/release-9-2-10.html

Comment: @JeffDiederiks I described why this works in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits#comment125095736_56753596) under [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753596/4494577). The answer describes a similar approach but applies the `PGDATA` environment variable in the run-time rather than build-time.

Answer (score 8):

You should be all set with the following command. The most important part is the PGDATA location, which should be anything but the default.

```
docker run -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/pgdata -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=YourPa$$W0rd -d postgres
```

Comment: I think it does not answer the question, it just stores the data separately, right?

Comment: @LukasSalich This "kinda'" answers the question. If you run the container using this command-line then data will be stored outside the volume declared in the dockerfile (which is `/var/lib/postgresql/data`). This means that once you fill such database with data and then take a snapshot with `docker commit`, the data will become a part of the commited image. If you run another container (even on another host) using this image the data will be there from the start.

Comment: And this is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to save data during a commit since the data resides on a mount which is specific for that container and will get removed once you run `docker rm <container ID>` but you can use data volumes to share and reuse data between container and the changes made are directly on the volume.

You can use `docker run -v /host/path:/Container/path` to mount the volume to the new container.

Please refer to: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: Volumes aren't removed when you run `docker rm <container id>`. You have to explicitly specify the `-v` option i.e. `docker rm -v <container id>`.

Answer (score 0):

For keeping permanent data such as databases, you should define these data volumes as external, therefore it will not be removed or created automatically every time you run docker-compose up or down commands, or redeploy your stack to the swarm.

```
...
volumes:
  db-data:
    external: true
...
```

then you should create this volume:

```
docker volume create db-data
```

and use it as data volume for your databse:

```
...
db:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
...
```

In production, there are many factors to consider when using docker for keeping permanent data safely, specially in swarm mode, or in kubernetes cluster.