# New version of postgresql docker container doesn't have the new added data

Tags: database, postgresql, docker

I am using a postgreSQL docker image.
When I inspect the docker image running I have the following configuration:

```
"Volumes" : {
     "var/lib/postgresql": {}
};
```

I want to run the docker container, make changes to the postgresql data bases and create another version of the docker container with those changes. For that I use the following command:

```
docker commit –m “Add data” –a “My User Name” \7b827 miguelbgouveia/postegresql:version2
```

The I run this new container expecting that the added data be present. Like this:

```
docker run -d --name db –p 5432:5432 miguelbgouveia/postgresql:version2
```

The problem is all the new data added is not present in the new running container. This is normal? How can I create a new container containing all the data base changes?

Comment: Duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits ?

Answer (score 3):

Volumes are outside of the Docker layered filesystem. Any changes you make there are persisted in the volume, not in the image.