# Docker : accessing MySQL container during Tomcat image build

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile, expect, jahia

I'm trying to create a **Docker** installation of **Jahia** CMS (Digital Experience Manager).

I need :

1. a **MySQL** container
2. a **Jahia** container (embedded **Tomcat**)

The trick is that during the Jahia container **build** (product installation using [Expect](https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index)), I need to access the MySQL container (connection check required).

**MySQL Dockerfile** :

```
FROM mysql:5.6
```

**Jahia Dockefile** :

```
FROM centos:centos6

# Install dependencies
RUN yum -y update && yum -y install ...

# Download Digital Experience Manager 7.1.1
RUN wget -q https://www.jahia.com/downloads/jahia/digitalexperiencemanager7.1.1/DigitalExperienceManager-EnterpriseDistribution-7.1.1.0-r53717.3663.jar -O /tmp/DigitalExperienceManager.jar

# Download MySQL connector (only needed for standalone db installation)
RUN wget -q http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar -O /usr/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar

# Launch installation using Expect to automate user input
COPY jahia_conf.exp /tmp/configuration.exp
RUN expect /tmp/configuration.exp

# Start Jahia
/opt/DigitalExperienceManager-EnterpriseDistribution-7.1.1.0/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh jpda run
```

**Expect script** (*jahia_conf.exp*)

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn java -jar /tmp/DigitalExperienceManager.jar -console

# Installation directory
expect "Select target path"
send "/opt/DigitalExperienceManager-EnterpriseDistribution-7.1.1.0\r"

# MySQL connector JAR file
expect "Specify the path to the downloaded driver JAR file"
send "/usr/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar\r"

# Database configuration
expect "Database URL (*)"
send "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/jahia?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useServerPrepStmts=false\r"
```

Of course I get an error during image build because it checks the connection right after database URL input :

> An error occurred while establishing the connection to the database
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..

Indeed I'm just **building** the Jahia image, so the `mysql` container is not yet accessible (even if running).

How to deal with this kind of situation (when you need to access another container during build) ?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to access mysql during the container build? Is there a reason you can't put `expect /tmp/configuration.exp` and the final command to start Jahia into an entrypoint.sh that runs on container start?

Comment: If I put it as entrypoint it will install the whole CMS each time I stop/start the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/). You may have to run the `configuration.exp` script to set up Jahia by exec'ing into your container. Then use docker commit to save the changes to the file system into a new image. That image should persist the initial configuration.

Be mindful that volumes are not included in a docker commit, as they live outside Docker's union file system. It doesn't look like you're declaring any volumes in your Dockerfile, so it probably won't be a problem for you.
 [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits) elaborates on docker commit and database volumes, but the premise is the same for any container.

Comment: Finally I simply used the solution stated in your comment, namely executing the Jahia installation on container run. So I set a shell script as entrypoint command (docker compose) in which I simply check if Jahia is already installed, and launch the installation only if needed. That way I can rebuild/restart my images/containers without worrying about committing each time.

Answer (score 1):

As MySQL server will also be in a container, I don't think you should configure it at build time, as you can't assume the database will be up.

Unfortunately, i don't know  how 'expect' tool works, but ideally you should link the Database in Jahia container only at container startup. This can be done by injecting it through configuration (environment variable or something else you can inject when you start the container)

That means the MySQL container should have the DB installed in a separated process. On our side for example, we do this by running the sql scripted provided in jahia code directly on the database.

With this solution, you ensure that you don't need your database preinstalled  while building.

**edit:** indeed, Jahia is doing some checks on the database at build time, but you can add an input so Jahia doesn't actually need to perform operation on the DB.  It uses izpack autoplay file. That allows to replay the installation.

The DB setup part is the following:

```
<com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel id="dbSettings">
<userInput>
<entry key="dbSettings.connection.url.mssql" value="jdbc:sqlserver://DB_SERVER;DatabaseName=DB_NAME;"/>
<entry key="dbSettings.dbms.createTables" value="false"/>
<entry key="dbSettings.connection.username" value="DB_USER"/>
<entry key="dbSettings.dbms.storeFilesInDB" value="false"/>
<entry key="dbSettings.connection.driver.mssql" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
<entry key="dbSettings.connection.password" value="DB_PASSWORD"/>
</userInput>
</com.izforge.izpack.panels.UserInputPanel>
```

This assume you have a DB server somewhere unfortunately. On our side we use a fake instance as we request not doing the installation during the build.

Comment: But Jahia installation asks for the database to be up, else it fails. It's not a choice from me to check this at build time, it is requested by the Jahia installation process. (Expect is simply a tool that allow to automatically send user input when prompted during installation process, it is not directly linked to the problem, I could have ignored it in the question).

Comment: I checked again our code and you are right, there is a database check during the build. We are using the installation through the jar, providing a xml file as parameter (so we do not need Expect in our case). I ll update my answer to provide the xml part.

Comment: Actually Expect is doing roughly the same thing as izpack. I could use a fake MySQL instance for installation but I suspect Jahia is also doing some configuration there, so it may be risky to simply come back to modify the DB settings after installation to use the containerized one. I will contact Jahia support to get their opinion about that.