# Installing Python 3.8 from with a postgres Docker container

Tags: python, docker, debian, python-3.8

I am confronted with a somewhat unexpected problem - I am having problems installing Python 3.8 in a Docker container.

I have created a Dockerfile that is intended to serve as my test DB.  As part of its creation, it needs to run a Python script to populate it with test data.  However, I cannot do what I thought would be the easiest step: installing Python.

```
FROM postgres

# Install Python dependencies ---------
RUN apt-get update && apt dist-upgrade -y
RUN apt install software-properties-common --yes
RUN apt-get install ca-certificates --yes
RUN gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa --yes
RUN apt install python3.8 --yes
RUN python3.8 --version
```

Somewhat to my surprise, only Python 3.7 is available through apt-get.  The approved method for getting Python 3.8 it to use deadsnakes - but this creates the following errors:

```
Step 12/33 : RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa --yes
 ---> Running in 17d490c0b568
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp8n9r_96q/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmp8n9r_96q/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key BA6932366A755776: public key "Launchpad PPA for deadsnakes" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

As per various posts I've found, I've added:

```
RUN apt-get install ca-certificates --yes
RUN gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support
```

And although they appear to do no harm (and the latter appears to get rid of a second error message from gpg), they do not solve the problem...

Comment: How about one container based on a `postgres` image for the database and one container based on `python` for the Python application?

Comment: @KlausD. I certainly have no objections to that, but I've been struggling to figure out how to save a populated postgress image.  I need to be able to do this anyway (for my production database), so all hints and tips welcome!

Comment: You can't save a populated PostgreSQL image (but you can store its actual data in a volume or host directory).  See for example [docker postgres with initial data is not persisted over commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits).  As @KlausD. suggests, a separate container to load the seed data is probably the right approach.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidMaze.  A colleague and I are just looking at this now, but we're trying to find the "official" way of extracting the data from Django to put on the volume....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that installing Python 3.8 (while the latest distribution is Python 3.7) on a debian container is more trouble than it was worth.

My workaround was to create a second Docker container running Python.  This populated the Postgres container in a one-off operation.

Comment: would you be able to edit with your final docker file?

Comment: @DBA108642 how do you mean?