# Changes in container not persisted after docker commit

Tags: postgresql, docker

I just create a container like:

```
docker run --name mypostgres \
--publish 5432:5432 \
--net=apinetwork \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pwd \
-e POSTGRES_DB=db_uso \
-d postgres
```

I connect in the database and create some tables and objects...

After this I commit;

```
docker commit mypostgres user/mypostgres
```

But when I create other container from this image:

```
docker run --name mypostgres2 \
--publish 5432:5432 \
--net=apinetwork \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
-e POSTGRES_DB=correntista \
-d user/mypostgres
```

I don't see my objects that I created inside!

Please help me.

Comment: Before you create a new container, can you try disconnecting and re-connecting to the database and verifying that your changes are still there

Comment: Thanks @smac89. Yes. I stopped the conteiner and start again and all my objects was there. But when a use the docker commit the image not have my objects. I tryied to do this with my base container running and after tryied agian with the container stoped. But nothing works

Comment: The question @MarcelloRomani linked to describes the situation pretty well; you need to create a Docker volume here and mount it with a `docker run -v` option.  In general you should almost never use `docker commit` since it leads to unreproducible images.  (If `user/mypostgres` is based on PostgreSQL 13.4, and if hypothetically there was a critical security version in that release, how would you update that image?)

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely you are not seeing the changes because the volume created with the original container is not being used by the new container.

*See [Persist the DB](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/05_persisting_data/) Docker tutorial.*

---

You need to explicitly create a volume, and make sure it is being used in the new container.

```
$ docker volume create my-pg-db
$ docker run --name mypostgres \
  --publish 5432:5432 \
  --net=apinetwork \
  -v my-pg-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pwd \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=db_uso \
  -d postgres
```

This means it may not even be necessary to make a copy of your container, if all the changes you are doing are on the DB. The volume which contains the DB is what you need to preserve!

And make sure you [mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) and use it whenever you want to start the container.

Comment: If the database data is in the container's filesystem though - with no use of volumes - and that container is `commit`ed to a new image, then why is that data (a new layer) not picked up in the new container?

Comment: OK found the answer... on SO :)

Comment: @MarcelloRomani please share your answer, or give us a link :)

Comment: I posted it as a proper answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason data is not persisted is explained in this other SO question:

[docker postgres with initial data is not persisted over commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits)

> The problem is that the postgres Dockerfile declares "/var/lib/postgresql/data" as a volume. This is a just a normal directory that lives outside of the Union File System used by images. Volumes live until no containers link to them and they are explicitly deleted.

which is why you need externally managed volumes like @smac90 wrote.

Source:
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/5c0e796bb660f0ae42ae8bf084470f13417b8d63/Dockerfile-debian.template#L186