# Shutdown Postgres process in Docker but keep container alive?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm using the official Postgres Docker Image, namely `postgres:12.9-alpine`

I'd like to run `docker container commit` on a container whose Postgres process has been terminated gracefully.

When I attempt to run `pg_ctl stop -D <datapath>`, I do in fact shut down the Postgres process, but the container comes down with it.

Is it possible to keep the container alive so that I can commit the container to a new image in a clean state?

Comment: A principle of containers is that they only run as long as their main process (postgres in this case) is running. Once that stops - for whatever reason - the container will be discarded. So unless you use a custom image that will have a 'running' process that is not directly the postgres process then no, you cannot access the container after postgres stops.

Comment: Committing a container, in general, is rarely a best practice.  For this particular setup [you can't commit most database containers and preserve their data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits).  A better approach would be to take a backup of the database data, either using PostgreSQL's native `pg_dump` tool or backing up the underlying volume contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can commit a new image from an exited container, so there's no need to keep it running. Just don't automatically remove the container on exit.

Comment: The container doesn't show up in `docker ps -a`