# Commited SQL Server image does not work when using a mount

Tags: sql-server, docker, ubuntu-20.04, docker-volume

My committed image of SQL Server does not seem to work when using a mount.  When not mounted, the image contains the changes I made but when when I mount the data directory I don't see the committed changes.

**Step to reproduce:**

Run a container with SQL server 2019.

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword123" -p 14350:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Connect to this SQL Server and create a database named TestDB.

Commit the container, tagged as testDB, and delete the container. (My contianer ID is cabc3ac26dd0)

```
docker commit cabc3ac26dd0 testdb
docker container stop cabc3ac26dd0 
docker rm cabc3ac26dd0
```

Run a container with this new image.

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword123" -p 14350:1433 -d testdb
```

Connect to this SQL sServer container and you will see the new TestDB database.  This is your new database, saved as part of the commit.  This shows that the commit worked.

Remove the container, and run a new container for testdb with the data drive mounted to your local filesystem.

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword123" -p 14350:1433 --mount type=bind,source=C:\Users\me\testdbfiles\mssql\data,target=/var/opt/mssql/data -d testdb
```

Connect to this sql server conatiner and you **will not** see the new TestDB.

It seems that the commit has worked when I run without the mount.  When I run with the mount, I don't see the changes for my committed image.

1. This docker run command is the same one I have used for months.
   This problem started about a week ago, near when I upgraded to docker
   desktop 4.12.0.
2. The mounted location (C:\Users\me\testdbfiles\mssql\data) has the
   sql server database files (such as master.mdf), therefore the mount
   the syntax must be correct.
3. Running a select from sys.databases shows the new TestDB when I am not mounted.  When mounted, this select doesn't show this database.  This indicates that the master database itself is different when mounted.
4. Listing the contents of the /var/opt/mssql/data shows the TestDB file when not mounting, but does not show them when mounting.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

How can I troubleshoot what happens during the mounting phase?

**Update:** I also added a new sql server login to the image.  When I mount I don't see the login, with no bind mount the login is there.

Comment: Isn't this what you more or less asked the [other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73827458/docker-sql-server-loses-my-database-when-using-a-bind-mount#73827458), looking at this again.

Comment: Sort of.  But I gave up on that because it was very specific to my workload, and the post was long an rambling.  I did another test, with an empty database and posted steps to reproduce it.  I have removed that other post.  It was poorly written.

Comment: When you create a mount you **hide** any folders and files that were previously residing at the mount point, replacing them with any folders or files that now exist at the external source. The original files still exist inside the layered file system of the image, but the running container processes can't see them any more because the mount has replaced them. In the case of Docker SQL Server images the SQL Server service will recreate the master, model, msdb and tempdb files in the mount as it starts - these are new files, not the old ones, which is why the login you created no longer exists.

Comment: `docker commit` is pretty much never a best practice.  One of its limitations is that it will not persist data in mounted volumes, either because of an explicit `docker run -v` mount or because its image includes a `VOLUME` directive.  This usually means that, if you do incorrectly `docker commit` a container based on a database, the resulting non-reproducible image won't contain the database data (for example, [docker postgres with initial data is not persisted over commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits)).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the behavior is exactly as you described it.  However, isn't it making the new files by copying them from the image which should have new login?  

I did the commit on the contianer before I used the mount.  All files should have been in the container when I did the commit.

Comment: No, it doesn't copy the old files out of the image's /var/opt/mssql/data folder. From the point of view of the running processes inside the container when you create the mount the /var/opt/mssql/data folder is a new, empty folder. While starting up the SQL Server service detects that the master, model, msdb and tempdb .mdf and .ldf files are missing from the /var/opt/mssql/data folder and so copies brand new (template) versions into there. These aren't your old, modified files, these are essentially "factory reset" files.