# Can't replace pg_hba.conf when create my custom container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need the next:

```
1. Create custom image base on image postgres.9.6
2. Create custom container from my custom image
3. Replace original file pg_hba.conf by my custom file
```

The difference between this to files is only in this line:

In origal **pg_hba.conf** file:

```
host    all             all            127.0.0.1/0             trust
```

In my **pg_hba.conf** file.

```
host    all             all            0.0.0.0/0                trust
```

Here my Dockerfile.

```
FROM postgres:9.6.24

ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

# Create folder Downloads in Docker
WORKDIR /Downloads

COPY /plv8_v.2.x ./Downloads

RUN dpkg -i Downloads/plv8-96_2.1.0-2_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i Downloads/v8_3.14.5.10-26_amd64.deb

COPY /postgresql /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/

# Overwrite file pg_hba.conf to avoid password prompt
COPY pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

Create my custom image by this command:

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

Image success created. Nice.

Create my custom container from my custom imeage

```
 docker run --name my_container --restart=always -d -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 my_image
```

But the container **is not started**.
If I comment this line

```
COPY pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

the problem is gone. Then the container is success start.
I want to avoid of PostgreSQL's password prompt. That's why I want to replace pg_hba.conf

So I need to replace **pg_hba.conf**. So how I can do this?

Comment: Since the file is in the data directory and that will usually have a volume mounted over it, I'm not sure adding the file in the image will be effective.  Also see [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75426826/10008173) which discusses this from the volume point of view.  When you say "it doesn't start", what does happen?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
Not need to copy pg_hba.conf to Docker container. It's enought to use

environment virable:

```
ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

So here result Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6.24

ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust

# Create folder Downloads in Docker
WORKDIR /Downloads

COPY /plv8_v.2.x ./Downloads

RUN dpkg -i Downloads/plv8-96_2.1.0-2_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i Downloads/v8_3.14.5.10-26_amd64.deb

COPY /postgresql /usr/share/postgresql/9.6/extension/
```

And now it's work. It's not ask me about PostgreSQL password anymore.