# Save the current state of the docker container into a new docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra, cql

I have a simple project that has a Cassandra database in a docker container. The database contains only one keyspace and a table. I want to save the container as an image after creating the keyspace and the table. So in the new docker image, it will contain both. The main idea behind this is to use this new image to create [TestContainers](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/) during the testing of the functionalities of the application. Also, I won't need to every time generate the table since the new container will have it anyway, and in the test classes I can only focus on the actual functionality testing.

The project contains a student service that has CRUD operations to add, update, get, and delete student data. I created the first container using the following docker-compose file

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:latest
    container_name: test-container-student
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
    volumes:
      - C:/Users/{username}/Documents/backup/student:/var/lib/cassandra
```

Student class

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then I ran this Program.cs to generate the keyspace and the students table.

```
using Cassandra;

namespace TestProject;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Define the Cassandra cluster
        var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
            .AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1") 
            .Build();

        // Create a session
        var session = cluster.Connect();

        // Create the keyspace if it doesn't exist
        session.Execute(@"
            CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS StudentDetails
            WITH replication = {
                'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
                'replication_factor': 1
            }");


        session.Execute(@"
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StudentDetails.students (
            student_id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
            first_name TEXT,
            last_name TEXT,
            age INT
        )");
    }
}
```

After running the project it successfully creates the keyspace and table. And I saved the docker image using `docker commit`. Then I generated a new docker container using this new docker image. But when checked the tables in the new container, I realized that the table I previously created, is not there. Is there any way that I can successfully save the image with the table? Thank you.

Comment: Could you try to remove the volume from your docker-compose and retry everything again? It may interfere with your new container.

Comment: Hi @kevto, first I tried without adding a volume. But it also didn't work as expected.

Comment: Database container images tend to contain a `VOLUME` directive, which means the database data will _always_ be stored in a volume, and `docker commit` won't include it in an image.  Questions like [docker postgres with initial data is not persisted over commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27377876/docker-postgres-with-initial-data-is-not-persisted-over-commits) suggest changing the data directory to avoid this.  But in any case `docker commit` is almost never a best practice (how would you recreate the image if you need to update the database version?).

Comment: @DavidMaze yes it is not the best solution. May be I can try adding cql query as an entryPoint as in the reference question you sent. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done the same thing for `superset` and worked. Following are the steps I followed.

1. Get running `cassandra:latest` ID using `sudo docker ps`
2. `sudo docker commit <docker-container-id-of-cassandra> new-cassandra`
3. Go to your `docker-compose.yml` file location `sudo docker-compose down`
4. Edit `docker-compose.yml` with new cassandra image

```
version: '3'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: new-cassandra
    container_name: new-container-student # <- change name here
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
    volumes:
      - C:/Users/{username}/Documents/backup/student:/var/lib/cassandra
```

5. `sudo docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Hi @sachith, Can you please explain what is happening here? It's not very clear where did you add your tables to the container.

Comment: @Panda153 You mounted your docker image to local and in new image also uses the same volume. So data will be available. Docker commit will create a new image (if you had added additional configs to container) and can be used in new as fresh.

Comment: This is working. ```WithBindMount("C:\\Users\\{username}\\Documents\\backup\\student", "/var/lib/cassandra")``` worked for testContainers. :)

Comment: If all of the data is in the named volume, you don't need the `docker commit` step. You can (and should) use the unmodified original image in combination with the persistent data volume.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I added that step for the worst case, assuming changes were made to docker container on run time,